# Pandas: Replace/ Change Duplicate values within a Time Range

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I have a pandas data-frame where I am trying to replace/ change the duplicate values to 0 (don't want to delete the values) within a certain range of days.

So, in example given below, I want to replace duplicate values in all columns with 0 within a range of let's say 3 (the number can be changed) days. Desired result is also given below

```
              A   B  C

01-01-2011   2   10  0
01-02-2011   2   12  2
01-03-2011   2   10  0
01-04-2011   3   11  3
01-05-2011   5   15  0
01-06-2011   5   23  1
01-07-2011   4   21  4
01-08-2011   2   21  5
01-09-2011   1   11  0
```

So, the output should look like

```
              A   B  C

01-01-2011   2   10  0
01-02-2011   0   12  2
01-03-2011   0   0   0
01-04-2011   3   11  3
01-05-2011   5   15  0
01-06-2011   0   23  1
01-07-2011   4   21  4
01-08-2011   2   0   5
01-09-2011   1   11  0
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does `within a range of 3` mean? You have what seems to be a `DatetimeIndex` but it's not monotonic, so are we considering the dates or just the row index? Your question asks for `within a Time Range` but your output completely ignores the time

Comment: Hi Alollz, thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have fixed the dates. We are considering the dates, so I am looking for 3 days window where values should not be repeated and if they are, then replace the repeated values with 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use df.shift() for this to look at a value from a row up or down (or several rows, specified by the number x in .shift(x)).

You can use that in combination with .loc to select all rows that have a identical value to the 2 rows above and then replace it with a 0.

Something like this should work :
(edited the code to make it flexible for endless number of columns and flexible for the number of days)

```
numberOfDays = 3 # number of days to compare

for col in df.columns:
    for x in range(1, numberOfDays):
        df.loc[df[col] == df[col].shift(x), col] = 0

print df
```

This gives me the output:

```
            A   B  C
date
01-01-2011  2  10  0
01-02-2011  0  12  2
01-03-2011  0   0  0
01-04-2011  3  11  3
01-05-2011  5  15  0
01-06-2011  0  23  1
01-07-2011  4  21  4
01-08-2011  2   0  5
01-09-2011  1  11  0
```

Comment: Thanks Niels, but my actual data-frame is huge (with >50 columns and >1000 rows) and I am looking for a range of 5, 10 or probably 20 days. Manually specifying number in .shift() function will not be a practical solution.

Comment: Okay, I changed the code to make it more flexible. Maybe make your intentions/question a bit more clear in your next question. I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @SpghttCd and Niels Henkens . The code is pretty intuitive and it works like a charm!

Comment: Great James11 that it worked. It's good practice to label the best/correct answer to your as 'anwered'. This also alerts other users that your question doesn't need an answer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find anything better than looping over all columns, because every column leads to a different grouping.
First define a function which does what you want at grouped level, i.e. setting all but the first entry to zero:

```
def set_zeros(g):
    g.values[1:] = 0
    return g

for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = df.groupby([c, pd.Grouper(freq='3D')], as_index=False)[c].transform(set_zeros)
```

This custom function can be applied to each group, which is defined by a time range (`freq='3D'`) and equal values of a column within this period. As the columns generally have their equal values in different rows, this has to be done for each column in a loop.

Change `freq` to `5D`, `10D` or `20D` for your other considerations.
For a detailed description of how to define the time period see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases